# how to pass split values into a loop in ansible based on input range?

Tags: loops, ansible, jinja2, regexp-replace, ansible-template

I am pretty new to Ansible loops.
I am trying to replace a set of ip addresses (`oldip` to `newip`) in a file.
It needs to accept the input ip address as a dynamic list in the form `oldip1:newip1,oldip2:newip2,oldip3:newip3...`

I want to split the above ip address pair (`old:new`) and then pass them over to Ansible `replace` module in a loop based on input list.

I am trying something like this, but am stuck on how to pass the dynamic range of ip address pair into the loop.

My input variable is like `192.123.12.11;192.123.12.20, 192.123.12.12;192.123.12.19 , 192.123.12.13;192.123.12.18 ...` (dynamic ip pairs range)

```
vars: 
  ip_pairs: oldIP_newIP
tasks: 
  - debug: "{{ oldIP_newIP.split (',') }}"
  - replace: 
      path: /home/ubuntu/cassandra.properties
      regexp: "{{ item.regexp }}"
      replace: "{{ item.replace }}"
      backup: yes
    with_items: 
      - { regexp = "{{ oldIP }}", replace = "{{ newIP }}"
      - { regexp = "{{ oldIP }}", replace = "{{ newIP }}"
      .
      .
      .
      .
```

This loop should continue based on input ip pairs entry (5 times for 5 ip pairs (`old;new`).

Comment: In the beginning you say `old:new` and in the end you state `old;new` what is your delimiter there?  A semilicon `;` or a colon `:`?

Comment: I am going to assume that your input is correct and your typo is just in the intro to your question, feel free to correct me if my assumption is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something really useful you can use in order to achieve this is the fact that you can register variables at the task level, via the `vars` property.

For exemple:

```
- name: This will display 'bar', the content of foo
  debug:
    msg: "{{ foo }}"
  vars:
    foo: 'bar'
```

Base on this, you can achieve what you want quite easily doing:

```
- name: Replace IPs
  replace:
    path: /home/ubuntu/cassandra.properties
    regexp: "{{ oldNewIp[0] | trim }}"
    replace: "{{ oldNewIp[1] | trim }}"
    backup: yes
  vars:
    oldNewIp: "{{ item.split(';') }}"
  with_items: "{{ ipPairs.split(',') }}"
```

Please mind that I added some extra Jinja [`trim`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#trim) in order to cope with the fact that, in your example input, you do have some space after your commas.

Here is a full example play to demo this:
Given the playbook

```
- hosts: local
  vars:
    ipPairs: '192.123.12.11;192.123.12.20, 192.123.12.12;192.123.12.19, 192.123.12.13;192.123.12.18'

  tasks:
    - name: Create an example file to replace in
      copy:
        dest: /tmp/ips.txt
        content: ''

    - name: Populate a file with old IPs
      lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/ips.txt
        line: "{{ oldNewIp[0] | trim }}"
      vars:
        oldNewIp: "{{ item.split(';') }}"
      with_items: "{{ ipPairs.split(',') }}"

    - name: Replace IPs
      replace:
        path: /tmp/ips.txt
        regexp: "{{ oldNewIp[0] | trim }}"
        replace: "{{ oldNewIp[1] | trim }}"
        backup: yes
      vars:
        oldNewIp: "{{ item.split(';') }}"
      with_items: "{{ ipPairs.split(',') }}"
```

I have the following play:

```
/ # ansible-playbook -i inventory.yaml play.yaml 

PLAY [local] *********************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************
[WARNING]: Platform linux on host local is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python3,
but future installation of another Python interpreter could change this. See
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more
information.
ok: [local]

TASK [Create an example file to replace in] **************************************************************
changed: [local]

TASK [Populate a file with old IPs] ***********************************************************************
changed: [local] => (item=192.123.12.11;192.123.12.20)
changed: [local] => (item= 192.123.12.12;192.123.12.19)
changed: [local] => (item= 192.123.12.13;192.123.12.18)

TASK [Replace IPs] ***************************************************************************************
changed: [local] => (item=192.123.12.11;192.123.12.20)
changed: [local] => (item= 192.123.12.12;192.123.12.19)
changed: [local] => (item= 192.123.12.13;192.123.12.18)

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************
local                      : ok=4    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

/ # cat /tmp/ips.txt
192.123.12.20
192.123.12.19
192.123.12.18
```

Comment: sure, did that!